# Google Maps SDK for iOS touch on SubView

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

after updating to Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.3.1.3848 I can not catch touch events on a subview added to the MapView anymore.

Thanks for your help!
Sven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm don't using GSMMapView as root view anymore. Just adding it to self.view by using

```
[self.view insertSubview:_googleMapView atIndex:0];
```

instead.

Comment: I'm using 1.6.1.6332 SDK in my project and the only way I can get the map to show is by `self.view = self.googleMap` doing any `addSubView` or `insert` of sorts doesn't work.And the way i get the map to show doesn't respect all my subviews gesture recognizers. Any Ideas?